# How can I un-delete an uncommitted `svn rm foo`?

Tags: svn

I've used `svn rm foo` on a number of files that I now no longer want to delete. I haven't yet committed the changes. How do I nullify the `svn rm` commands, either file-by-file or in one fell swoop?

I know how to restore deleted files that have been removed from the repo, but I don't want to have to commit this change, then restore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`svn revert whateveryoudeleted`

Comment: but when i do this, it says 'whatever skipped', what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Use svn revert (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re25.html)